# shell script: replace the contents

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep

I have a file with the following contents

FileName:**VersionInfo.properties**

```
Installed Version:13.7.0-2
Previous Version:13.6.0-12
```

FileName: **main.sh**

```
#!/bin/ksh
new_maj_version=$1 # sample content: 13.7.0
new_min_version=$2 # sample content: 4
```

Every time I run my main.sh I want it to edit my VersionInfo.properties file. The Installed Version should shift to Previous version and my new_maj_version and new_min_version to be placed in Installed version. How can I achieve it?

**Sample output after running my main.sh**

FileName:**VersionInfo.properties**

```
Installed Version:13.7.0-4
Previous Version:13.7.0-2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: (save it to your main.sh):

```
#!/bin/ksh
awk -F: -v a="$1" -v i="$2" 'NR==1{n=$2;print $1":"a"-"i;next}{print $1":"n}'  /VersionInfo.properties > /tmp/tmpVersion && mv /tmp/tmpVersion VersionInfo.properties
```

try with

```
main.sh "13.7.0" "4"
```

Comment: It worked. Now I have rollback.sh file in which the version number is hardcoded as `uninstall_rpm ClientInfrastructure 13.6.0-12`. How can I make this rollback script to pick up the `Previous Version` in `VersionInfo.properties` instead of hard coding it?

Comment: your "rollback.sh" problem is not clearly described. what is hardcoded? after the rollback.sh executed, what would happen? where comes the part `uninstall_rpm ClientInfrastructure`?  I cannot help further. sorry. This answer is to your current question. If it solved your problem, I am happy.

Comment: Your answer solved my intial issue.if you want to solve the other issue as well please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597901/shell-script-replace-contents

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
 sed -e "/Installed Version/{s/Installed Version:\(.*\)/Installed Version:$major_version-$minor_version\nPrevious Version:\1/; n}" -e '/Previous Version/{d}'
VersionInfo.properties
```

Comment: It did the trick only once.2nd time its not moving my Installed version to Previous version. `main.sh "13.7.0" "4"
Installed Version:13.7.0-4
Previous Version:13.6.0-12
(2nd time I ran it again)main.sh "13.7.0" "9"
Installed Version:13.7.0-9
Previous Version:13.6.0-12`

Comment: @sravs448, it works for me. Note that the command above writes the updated versions to standard output, you need to add the plumbing to update the original `VersionInfo.properties`. As long as you keep updating `$major_version` and `$minor_version` appropriately this will continue to work on subsequent runs