# shell script : replace contents

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have file with following info

FileName:**VersionInfo.properties**

```
Installed Version:13.7.0-2
Previous Version:13.6.0-12
```

FileName: **rollback.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
uninstall_rpm ClientInfrastructure $version
```

How can I get the value into variable **$version** from **Previous Version** of VersionInfo.properties file. $version should have the value **13.6.0-12**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` solution:

```
version=$(sed -n 's/Previous Version:\(.*\)/\1/p' VersionInfo.properties)
```

To use it in a script you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
version=$(sed -n 's/Previous Version:\(.*\)/\1/p' VersionInfo.properties)
uninstall_rpm ClientInfrastructure "$version"
```

If that is all you have in your script then you can basically do it on the command line.

```
uninstall_rpm ClientInfrastructure "$(sed -n 's/Previous Version:\(.*\)/\1/p' VersionInfo.properties)"
```

Comment: @anubhava haha, I started off writing `awk` solution then saw two versions already posted. Started off with `grep` and that was posted. So `sed` was my last choice. I am getting old ... not quite fast to keep up with everyone here ... ;)

Comment: This is only half-an-answer, though – it doesn't show how to use the `version` in the rollback.sh script.

Comment: @kojiro You need to show some confidence in OP's abilities for figuring that out! `:-)`

Comment: @JS웃 I spent too much time on Freenode in my youth to have confidence in people's ability to figure things out.

Comment: Sorry @kojiro I didn't mean to show any disrespect, I have learnt a lot from your answers here on SO and do appreciate your feedback. I have updated the answer to show the usage in a script.

Comment: @JS웃 it never occurred to me to think of what you said as disrespectful.

Comment: @kojiro Then all's well that ends well :)

Answer (score 2):

```
version=$(awk 'END {print $2}' FS=':' VersionInfo.properties)
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep + parameter expansion solution:

```
version=$(grep '^Previous Version:' VersionInfo.properties)
version=${version#*:}
uninstall_rpm ClientInfrastructure $version
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file's written like that you just need the variable `$version` exported properly.

```
version=$(awk -F: '/Previous Version/{print $2}') ./rollback.sh
```

if you really want to change the contents of `rollback.sh`, use ed:

```
ed rollback.sh <<< ",s/\$version/$(awk -F: '/Previous Version/{print $2}')/
w" # w must be on newline
```